# Errno 107 Transport endpoint is not connected.

Tags: python, odoo

Today I got this error message in my 
 `openerp server(v 6.0.2 running in Ubuntu 12.04 server)` and it shut down.

`WARNING: web-services:Netrpc: closing because of exception [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected.`

I needed to restart openerp server to get it start working.

What may have caused this issue and how can I prevent happening this?

Comment: Please provide the full exception.